# How do you test if batteries are good?

Tags: batteries

I have a huge flashlight which runs on eight D batteries. I gathered the eight batteries, but I'm not sure if they are all good, and I don't really want to test them all.

I tried testing them all out, two at a time on another smaller flashlight, but this took way too long. Is there any quick way to test if batteries are good?

Comment: <comments removed> Folks, if you would like to answer a question, please post it as a proper 'answer' below. Posting answers in comments does not allow that information to be vetted properly. And posting answer in comments makes it look like the author has been helped so people are less likely to post their solutions below. Please refrain from posting answers in comments. Thanks.

Comment: If it's a 9V battery instead, [try licking it!](https://www.sparkfun.com/news/1385) It's fun!

Comment: Not a life-hacky way, but you can buy all-purpose battery testers for about 2$ on eBay/Aliexpress/Amazon/etc. Search for "battery tester". I doubt there's any simpler and faster way of testing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can test if your batteries are dead by dropping them on a hard surface - just 5cm worked for me.

If your battery is alive, it will not bounce, and a discharged one will. Why?

> A non-rechargeable battery begins with zinc powder mixed into a gel containing a  manganese dioxide powder. As the battery discharges manganese dioxide powder changes to manganese oxide so the granules start to bond chemically. This packed-sand consistency reduces the anti bounce effect caused by the original gel mixture.

*[Source: Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/test-if-your-batteries-are-dead-by-dropping-them-on-a-h-1630525062)*

Anti bounce is caused because the gel inside moves slower than the battery, so as the battery tries to bounce back up, the gel inside is still falling and stops it.

Comment: Does it matter how you hold the battery when dropping it? I can imagine it's hard to see if the battery bounces, if you drop it on the shorter side (negative) and it will end up laying on the longer side.

Comment: I think drop onto the flat (—) side.

Comment: And can dropping it ruin it somehow? Can it hurt the manganese stuff and make the battery go bad/die?

Comment: @Msb doubt it...

Comment: @Tim Pity that you removed a meme (which comes from the same source), but I think it helps more people to find that Q&A solution page easier via different image search engines.

Comment: @kenorb I didn't like the way the batteries were bouncing everywhere - that's not how you should test them. I also thought that it detracted from the text, and was repeating information. I can see why it would be good, but people looking for this solution are (less) likely to be looking at images (I think).

Comment: Good one!  Didn't know!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

I touch "+" with tip of my tongue. If battery is dead, it is tasteless, otherwise it's like a lemon. Don't try it with 9 Volts or more - it's painfull. 1.5V is ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one with a bulb/LED and a paper clip...

Use the bulb from the flashlight or a LED.

- set the battery on the positive end of the battery to be tested.
- take a paper clip and bend it into a makeshift "C"
- touch one end of the paper clip to the negative (flat/bottom) end of the battery.
- touch the other end of the paper clip to the bulb side.

You may need to use adhesive tape to help you, or get a friend / third hand to help hold the items together to make a good contact.

If the battery is good, the bulb will light up (if correct connections are made on the battery AND bulb). 
The brighter the bulb, the more juice the battery has.

*NOTE:* If the bulb doesn't light up right away, make sure you fiddle with the connections a bit before you discard the battery.

Comment: If you have a flashlight bulb, why not just put them is the flashlight?

Comment: he has 8 of them and wants to know which ones are bad... all 8 are needed for the flashlight. This process of elimination will help him determine which ones need to be replaced out of the batch.

Comment: Ahh I see, yeah that would work then :)

Comment: Any explanation on the DV folks?

Comment: Not very hackish is it... I didn't DV btw?

Comment: circumventing a device and using a paperclip to test a battery isn't a hack?

Comment: I (personally) don't think so. But I'm gonna leave my upvote there...

Comment: I down voted because frankly this sounds more irritating and difficult than just using the flashlight as he did... Who has an LED lying around anyway? Probably people who own multimeters...

Comment: As pointed out in the original post, but edited badly in revisions, an LED cannot be simply connected to a battery without carefully matching the poles and the proper resistance in series. Reversing polarity will immediately burn out the LED before you even see it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can test your battery if you're not sure by voltmeter. Some bouncing bateries may be suitable for use.

Comment: Please limit your answer to just one solution. By having multiple solutions in one answer, if your answer is marked as accepted, the rest of us have no way to know which solution was the one that worked. Recommended reading: [Lifehacks Manifesto](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)